# changing the database scheme to avoid having multiple database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008

We have a web portal in our company that is written in asp.net MVC . right now each department have their own database but we want to avoid having multiple database because the database scheme is the same only it has diffrent data inside for each department.like each department has their own projects etc. how the database model should be changed in such a way to avoid having multiple database ?
also we want to share some elments like projects between diffrents department. how it could be done ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The single database that you have in mind would have to have its table re-designed such that you would be able to tell, for each record in each table, what department the record relates to. Essentially you would need to add a "DeptId" column to each root-level table.  By root level table I mean only the parents of foreign key relationships.  Eg, if you have an OrderHeader and OrderLines, only the OrderHeader table would need to have this DeptId column.  The lines relate to the header, so you won't need to add this column to the lines table as well.  Alternatively, if you have a Customer table, such that each customer belongs to only one department, then you would add the DeptId column to this customer table and then you won't need it on the OrderHeader table (since order header should be referencing Customer table)

Those tables/elements that you want to share between databases just would not have the DeptId column added to them.